# Functions are not valid as a React child. Hello there. I have an error in my code. Please tell me how to fix it

Tags: reactjs, function

```js
const PersonDetails = () => {
  return (
    <SwapiServiceConsumer>
      {({ getPerson }) => {
        return witdDetails(ItemDetails, getPerson);
      }}
    </SwapiServiceConsumer>
  );
};

export default PersonDetails;
```

- How to return withDetails in another method.
- I need to call withDetails (HOC) on the Consumer.

Comment: What is the error that you get and what throws it?

Comment: functions are not valid as a React child. return not a function.

Answer (score 2):

You have created a function inside `<SwapiServiceConsumer />`.

Among the JSX Code, you can only use or call function not define a function  :

for example :

```
const PersonDetails = () => {
    const myFunc = ({ getPerson }) => {
        return witdDetails(ItemDetails, getPerson);
    }
    return (
      <SwapiServiceConsumer>
        {myFunc(...)}
      </SwapiServiceConsumer>
    );
  };
  

  export default PersonDetails;
```

> this is not valid code

you must define function above of `return` then you can call it in `jsx`.

Comment: I still have the error. I'm dizzy. I have not been able to solve this problem for 2 weeks

Comment: please,publish your code on codesandbox, so than peaple can help you.

Comment: If I archive my code and send it to you, can you see the errors?

Comment: it's better that you publish to codesandbox.